# restrict child key in object to subtype of parent key

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of rules defined as an object, with values being an array of strings:

```
const RULES = {
    Foo: ["Rule1", "Rule2"],
    Bar: ["Rule1"],
} as const
```

I would like to use these `RULES` as a way to define another object:

```
const RELATIONS = {
    Foo: {
        Rule1: { newProp: "anyoldstringvalue" },
        Rule2: { newProp: "anynewstringvalue" }
    },
    Bar: {
        Rule1: { newProp: "anyoldstringvalue" }
    },
}
```

of course, I value type safety. So I came up with:

```
type mainRule = keyof typeof RULES // "Foo" | "Bar"
type subRules<T extends mainRule> = typeof RULES[T][number] // subRules<"Foo"> => "Rule1" | "Rule2"

type allRules = { [key in mainRule]: any }
type relation<T extends mainRule> = { [key in T]: { [key in subRules<T>]: { newProp: string } } }
```

This can safely type check `RELATIONS` against `RULES` BUT in a **verbose** manner:

```
const RELATIONS: allRules = {
  ...({
    Foo: {
      Rule1: { newProp: "anyoldstringvalue" },
      Rule2: { newProp: "anynewstringvalue" },
    },
  } as relation<"Foo">),
  ...({
    Bar: {
      Rule1: { newProp: "anyoldstringvalue" },
    },
  } as relation<"Bar">),
}
```

This way makes sure all the main rules are there and that each subRule follows the parent rules' definition. It also ensures no keys can be repeated or missed... but I have to make sure to add `as relation<"desiredKey">` for every child object. Also, there is the use of `any` which... is... undesirable to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like You have added excess nesting.

```
type relation<T extends mainRule> = { /* [key in T]: { */ [key in subRules<T>]: { newProp: string } }
```

This works for me:

```
type relation<T extends mainRule> = { [key in subRules<T>]: { newProp: string }}
type allRules = { [key in mainRule]: relation<key> }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgVQDIFEDKMC8MDeAoGQmAMRBAC4YBtAIjgFcAbAUwEYaAaGOp5gJhoBdDgSIAhAIYAnSrQYt2wvAF8YEiDFCQoePFACeAB2YwAthICWYeSewBrZvpAAzGAeMv4ydDAD0v7lIQGhgAH25JKRo9IxMIegAjGwgAHgAVGGYADyhmMAATDXMrGwA+LDdYz0RUNCo0wSowelME5ilBPwD4pN5UmiCacsxyngUQ8LH+aJjjGClmRgkoC3B0zJy8wrNLa15h3GoHfRgrGB7k9NLBShwYMGYAdwAFKRBDSmgpKwBzGGVlLMTBJGIxkhU7lRjqcwDsSrwbvNFstVmAUsdyoC8FpoPAUEgAIJpACSAHkAHJoSggsF9CGiQhBW4Mog2Vi3e5PV7vSg0CRgJyMQpQb5gH4ANxB9GYIWUIiIrN4fA5Dxebw+3H5+lVX1+ksY0tl8qIcpZkWZCsIbJVXPVvK1ICFurF+sN-2NhFNyiAA)

Comment: Never knew about using `key` as a subsequent type. Beautiful, thank you.